# aws no credentials error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, botocore

I am trying to setup dynamic thumbnail service [thumbor](https://github.com/thumbor/thumbor/) and to support s3 as storage, I need to setup this community powered [pip library for aws](https://github.com/thumbor-community/aws).

Its working well on my local environment but when I am trying to host it on one of our servers, I am getting NoCredentialsError. I am assuming this is because of difference versions of botocore (latest one and one installed by pip library). Here is error log:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 774, in get_component
    # client config from the session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 174, in <lambda>
    self._components.lazy_register_component(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 453, in get_data
    - agent_version is the value of the `user_agent_version`
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 119, in _wrapper
    data = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/loaders.py", line 364, in load_data
DataNotFoundError: Unable to load data for: _endpoints







2016-04-24 12:14:34 tornado.application:ERROR Future exception was never retrieved: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 230, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thumbor/handlers/imaging.py", line 31, in check_image
    exists = yield gen.maybe_future(self.context.modules.storage.exists(kw['image'][:self.context.config.MAX_ID_LENGTH]))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 455, in wrapper
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 443, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tc_aws/aws/storage.py", line 107, in exists
    self.storage.get(file_abspath, callback=return_data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 455, in wrapper
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 215, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 443, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tc_aws/aws/bucket.py", line 44, in get
    Key=self._clean_key(path),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 97, in call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name=self.operation, api_params=kwargs, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 60, in _make_api_call
    operation_model=operation_model, request_dict=request_dict, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 54, in _make_request
    request_dict=request_dict, operation_model=operation_model, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 32, in _send_request
    request = self.endpoint.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 126, in create_request
    operation_name=operation_model.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 90, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 124, in sign
    signer.add_auth(request=request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/auth.py", line 626, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

Could it be fixed with proper ordering in which I install libraries? Because the pip library removes existing newer version of botocore and installs an older version.

EDIT:

I am running processes with supervisor and it seems process cant access aws credentials

EDIT 2:

The issue got resolved with proper configuration of supervisor. The user for process started by supervisor did not have access to config file

Comment: It looks like your servers don't have credentials configured properly. How do you set up your credentials on your server vs your development machine? Regarding the versions, it looks like tc_aws has a hard dependency on botocore 1.2.0, and so it may not work if you upgrade beyond that point.

Comment: Yeah tc_aws downgrades botocore to 1.2.0. With current config, I tried to connect to s3 bucket from command line with boto3 and it works. I dont know what is proper order of installing these libraries.

Comment: @JordonPhillips I think I figured out the issue. I am running processes with supervisor and then process cant access aws credentials

Comment: Seems part of your problem cause by NOT using virtualenv.  You should not install package with "sudo pip".

Comment: @mootmoot yeah should use virtualenv and no sudo for pip installations

Comment: Another note, if you use script to run your virtualenv, use "source $HOME/<virtualenv_dir>/virtulenvname/bin/activate "  will push your script into your desire virtualenv.

Comment: please post your own answer for the solution and close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved with proper configuration of supervisor. The user for subprocess started by supervisor did not have access to aws config file. So it was working with local environment or creating process separately but not with supervisor.